# Android - change custom title view at run time

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am using a custom title view in my application for each activity. In one of the activities, based on button clicks I need to change the custom title view. Now this works fine every time when I make a call to setFeatureInt.

But if I try to update any items in the custom title (say change the text of a button or a text view on the title), the update does not take place.

Debugging through the code shows that the text view and button instances are not null and I can also see the custom title bar. But the text on the text view or the button is not updated. Has anyone else faced this problem?
How do I resolve it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's what I tried. Does not get updated even on calling postInvalidate.

```
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.text_title);

    TextView databar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    databar.setText("Some Text");
    databar.postInvalidate();

    Button leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_btn);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(mLeftListener);
    leftButton.setText("Left Btn");
    leftButton.postInvalidate();

    Button rightBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_btn);
    rightBtn.setOnClickListener(mRightListener);
    rightBtn.postInvalidate();
```

Comment: See this for alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634319/how-to-set-different-title-for-alert-dialog-when-webview-page-is-loaded/9394561#9394561

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that the only [`Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) implementation ([`PhoneWindow`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java;hb=HEAD)) uses a [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) in its `setFeatureInt` method and instantiates the new layout with [`inflate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) and `attachToRoot=true`. Consequently, when you call `setFeatureInt`, the new layouts are not *replaced* but *attached* to the internal title container and thus drawn on top of each other.

You can workaround this by using the following helper method instead of `setFeatureInt`. The helper simply removes all views from the internal title container before the new custom title feature is set:

```
private void setCustomTitleFeatureInt(int value) {
    try {
        // retrieve value for com.android.internal.R.id.title_container(=0x1020149)
        int titleContainerId = (Integer) Class.forName(
            "com.android.internal.R$id").getField("title_container").get(null);

        // remove all views from titleContainer
        ((ViewGroup) getWindow().findViewById(titleContainerId)).removeAllViews();

        // add new custom title view 
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, value);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // whatever you want to do here..
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether the current `setFeatureInt` behaviour is intended, but it is certainly not documented one way or the other which is why I'll take this to the android devs ;)

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, the aforementioned workaround is not ideal. Instead of relying on the `com.android.internal.R.id.title_container` constant you could simply *hide* the old custom title whenever you set a new one.

Let's assume you have two custom title layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/custom_title_1" ...
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/custom_title_2" ...
```

and you want to replace `custom_title_1` with `custom_title_2`, you could hide former and use `setFeatureInt` to add the latter:

```
findViewById(R.id.custom_title_1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_2);
```

Comment: What if any of these values (title_container, com.android.internal) in the later versions? Won't that affect the app?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Even though the com.android.internal.title_container constant is unlikely to change it is wrong to rely on it. This is an ugly workaround at best.

Comment: Thanks. This other solution works great. But I really don't understand why setFeatureInt should add views one above the other instead of replacing them? Esp with views which are bound to be singular - like the title!

Comment: Are you still able to put a progress bar in the title bar when you do this? If so -- what ID would you give the progress bar in the title.

Comment: @hwrdprkns of course, just make the progress bar part of the `<RelativeLayout/>` described above

Comment: Nicer: 
int titleContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/title_container", null, null);

Answer (score 14):

The correct way to do this is as follows:

```
requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE );
setContentView( R.layout.my_layout );
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title );
super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
```

Please note that the order of these statements is very important.

If you call super.onCreate() before any of the other statements you will get a blank title bar, which the hack of finding the title bar id and removing all the Views from it will fix but is not recommended.

Comment: OP is trying to change the title bar during runtime, after onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling invalidate or postInvalidate to redraw the view after updating the text?  If it's a custom View, can you put a breakpoint in the draw code to make sure it's getting called?

If you're on the UI thread, you can call 'invalidate' if you're not, you must call 'postInvalidate' or the view won't redraw itself.

Comment: If it helps, the view is redrawn coz I see the updated title bar but the controls on the title bar don't change

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2c worth:

When working in a MapActivity, requesting a custom title resulted in no title at all being shown.

Luckily, all I wanted to do was to set the title text differently, and I soon realized that just calling setTitle() inside of onCreate() worked for me (I called it after I called setContentView())

Sorry, but I don't have time right now to debug this any more and figure out why what I was doing didn't work, and why changing it made it work. As I said, just thought this might help someone out down the road.