# Custom dialog on Android: How can I center its title?

Tags: android, modal-dialog

I'm developing an Android application.

How can I center the title for a custom dialog that I'm using?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just found this post while trying to figure out how to do the same thing. Here's how I did it for anyone else that finds this in the future.

Style xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/PauseDialogTitle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="PauseDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
            <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        </style>
        <style name="DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

And in my activities onCreateDialog method for the dialog I want styled I create the dialog like this:

```
Dialog pauseDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);
pauseDialog.setTitle(R.string.pause_menu_label);
pauseDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pause_menu);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not center the title of the Dialog (HTC Wildfire running with Android 2.2.1)... Any ideas? Because intuitively your solution makes sense :)

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I've tested it on my Ideos and the emulator with 1.6 and 2.2 with no problems.

Comment: there is no "parent="@android:style/DialogWindowTitle"".

Comment: Yes there is. It's the 3rd entry in the android styles.xml. You can see it in the SDK in platforms\android-Z\data\res\values\styles.xml  (Replace Z with whatever version you have. It's there for 3 through 8 at the very least).

Comment: Nice digging.  You can actually simplify it to two layers.  Sorry for the poor formatting...      
  <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyDialogWindowTitle</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="MyDialogWindowTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

Comment: This is not correct answer.Correct one done by @LandL Partners

Comment: @ChrisJD how can we apply a light theme?

Comment: @Prakash the answer you pointed out, is valid for 'AlertDialog' and not for 'Dialog'

Answer (score 117):

Another way that this can be done programatically is using the setCustomTitle():

```
// Creating the AlertDialog with a custom xml layout (you can still use the default Android version)
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewname, null);
builder.setView(view);

TextView title = new TextView(this);
// You Can Customise your Title here 
title.setText("Custom Centered Title");
title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
title.setTextSize(20);

builder.setCustomTitle(title);
```

Comment: `R.layout.viewname` In this layout what has to be included?? only `TextView`??

Comment: The whole view section does not need to be included, this is only if you want to customise the default view of the AlertDialog. I do believe that it has to be a TextView.

Comment: I get a grey color border for this textview. How do I remove that? I have tried    title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_border); But this doesn't help. @LandLPartners

Comment: If you want to remove it from the entire AlertDialog then you can reference this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051581/how-to-remove-border-from-dialog.

Comment: best answer always!!

Comment: this should be accepted as answer. Anyways, works like charm.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in code as well. Assume you have dialog fragment then add following lines of code.

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    TextView textView = (TextView) this.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(textView != null)
    {
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me either.  findViewById(android.R.id.title); returns null.

Comment: it worked for me. I tried to get the ***TextView*** just after ***Dialog*** object instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @LandL Partners solution, but in Kotlin:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val inflater = this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewname, null)
builder.setView(view)
val title = TextView(this)
title.setText("Custom Centered Title")
title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
title.setTextSize(20)

builder.setCustomTitle(title)
```

Answer (score 2):

For your custom DialogFragment you can do this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(textView != null) {
        textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  findViewById(android.R.id.title); returns null.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programmatically without custom view:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    TextView textViewVanilla = (TextView) this.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(textViewVanilla != null)
    {
        textViewVanilla.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
    // support for appcompat v7
    TextView textViewAppcompat = (TextView) this.getDialog().findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.alertTitle);
    if(textViewAppcompat != null)
    {
        textViewAppcompat.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Thanks [@hesam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26269593/231590) for the idea. For appcompat layout see `Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/data/res/layout/alert_dialog_title_material.xml`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call `AlertDialog.Builder.setIcon()` and `AlertDialog.Builder.setTitle()`, then your custom dialog will not show the built-in/default title View. In this case you are able to add your custom title View:

```
AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View view)
```

As soon as it is you who create this View it is possible to implement any type of alignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView titleView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
if(titleView != null) {
titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

See [this KodeCenter article on Android Dialog and AlertDialog](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=2390ec63-63d7-4534-a76f-cc3b10497a2c) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)

            .setMessage(message)
            .create();
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    DialogTitle titleView=new DialogTitle(activity);
    titleView.setText(title);
    titleView.setPaddingRelative(32,32,32,0);
    alertDialog.setCustomTitle(titleView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some starting tips here for modifying the title of a dialog:
[Android - change custom title view at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820398/android-change-custom-title-view-at-run-time/866184#866184)
Don't know if it can be centered(haven't tried), but if it's a custom View I guess it's very possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nasty solution.... Extend AlertDialog.Builder and override all the methods (eg. setText, setTitle, setView, etc) to not set the actual Dialog's text/title/view, but to create a new view within the Dialog's View do everything in there. Then you are free to style everything as you please.

To clarify, as far as the parent class is concerned, the View is set, and nothing else.

As far as your custom extended class is concerned, everything is done within that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView titleText = (TextView) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
if(titleText != null) {
    titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Full code (using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder helpDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle(/*your title*/)
        .setMessage(/*your message*/)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /*you can do something here*/

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        /*you can do something here*/

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

final AlertDialog helpDialog = helpDialogBuilder.create();

helpDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        TextView titleText = (TextView) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
        if(titleText != null) {
            titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }

        TextView messageText = (TextView) helpDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if(messageText != null) {
            messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
    }
});

helpDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can do it in 1 line

```
dialog!!.window!!.attributes = dialog!!.window!!.attributes.apply { dimAmount = 0F }
```