# How to remove black border from AlertDialog builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created a custom dialog using `AlertDialog.builder`. In this dialog, I am not displaying the title. All works fine but there is a black border in the dialog. So can anyone tell me how can I remove this black border? The code and screenshot are below.

**Code in java:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder start_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog2,
                                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
            
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_layover_welcome_bg);

Button btnPositiveError = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_error_positive);   
btnPositiveError.setTypeface(m_facedesc);
            
start_dialog.setView(layout);
            
final AlertDialog alert = start_dialog.create();
alert.show();
            
btnPositiveError.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        alert.dismiss();
    }
});
```

**ScrrenShot**

[image]

Comment: I have removed backgrounds doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051581/how-to-remove-border-from-dialog. These questions could probably me merged

Answer (score 8):

```
Without creating a custom background drawable and adding a special style just add
```

one line to your code:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

More About Dialogs :

[Dilaogs](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/08/remove-title-bar-to-custom-dialog-and.html)

Comment: it clears all the background and not only the border! Anyway, it works for me, I use a color for the dialog Layour. Good!

Comment: Best answer for this problem, dont know why people are suggesting creating a custom theme for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line of code

```
AlertDialog.Builder start_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder start_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
```

you will be all set

Comment: It dont makes it transparent, just change the color to white

Answer (score 0):

Use Dialog class instead of AlertDialog

```
for eg - Dialog d = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
```

use setContentView instead of setView.

And set its theme to transparent.

Comment: I have used that..but thing is that it make the dialog fullscreen..so is there any option to prevent it form fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

> Just you insert

```
Dialog start_dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

> instead of this

```
AlertDialog.Builder start_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. It's better to use `Dialog` instead of `AlertDialog`.
That's my solution:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.Dialog_No_Border);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.some_dialog);
```

Contents of some_dialog.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/some_dialog_background">

        <TextView
           ...
       />

        <Button
           ...
       />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Dialog_No_Border" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
</style>
```

So, finally I have my custom dialog with background without borders.