# Change background of ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I am trying to change the background of a `ProgressDialog`. I searched the net and found various suggestions (like [How to remove border from Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051581/how-to-remove-border-from-dialog)), but I am unable to replace the actual background of the `ProgressDialog`. Instead I get another background (yellow) behind the dialog:

[image: Styled Dialog]

My style:

```
<style name="StyledDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
</style>
```

The code that launches the `ProgressDialog`:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.StyledDialog);
dialog.setTitle("The title");
dialog.setMessage("The message.");
dialog.show();
```

The drawable is the same 9 patch that is included in the SDK, I just changed to color. I would greatly appreciate some hints what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the title, message and image have their own background set rather than being transparent on the background of the dialog.  What you'd need to do is iterate over all children of the dialog view and set their background to transparent.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The comment of Aleks G (below the question) points in the right direction. The appearance of the dialog is defined by a separate style (`android:alertDialogStyle`). But one cannot apply the style directly to a `ProgressDialog`. Now, how do I get that yellow background?

**Step 1**: Define a theme that inherits from `Theme.Dialog`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

There, you can define things like the background color for the *whole* window (yellow in the question), font colors etc. What's really important is the definition of `android:alertDialogStyle`. This style controls the appearance of the black area in the question.

**Step 2**: Define the `CustomAlertDialogStyle`:

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

This sets the black area in the question to yellow.

**Step 3**: Apply `MyTheme` to the `ProgressDialog`, **not** `CustomAlertDialogStyle`:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyTheme);
```

And here's the result:

[image: Styled ProgressDialog]

The same procedure works with `AlertDialog` (which is the parent class of `ProgressDialog`).

Comment: Hello Aha
Very nice answer but Some border are still black.

Comment: Have you figured out how to remove the black border? @ShoebAhmedSiddique

Comment: Did someone test this on API level 8?
Not working for me :'(

Comment: @lyc001 you need the dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent); or <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

Answer (score -3):

You can try my [gist](https://gist.github.com/emreaktrk/9524973). It basicly sets a color filter on drawable.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ColoredProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
   public ColoredProgressBar(Context context) {
      super(context);
      if (!isInEditMode())
         init();
   }

   public ColoredProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      if (!isInEditMode())
         init();
   }

   public ColoredProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      if (!isInEditMode())
         init();
   }

   /**
    * Changes color.
    */
   private void init() {
      getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
   }
}
```