# how to set background image for progress dialog?

Tags: android, background, progressdialog

I'm new to Android..

In my app I'm using a progress dialog. I want to set background image for progress dialog. How do I implement this?

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FrontActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Grades. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my layout for custom progress dialog :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@layout/custom_rounded_box"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_background"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/light_gray_line" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".6" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dialogMessage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ok_btn" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dialogMessage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/cancel_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>`
```

And this is my custom Dialog class

```
    public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Button okButton;
Context mContext;
TextView mTitle = null;
TextView mMessage = null;
View v = null;
Button cancelButton;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the mTitle */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_box);
    v = getWindow().getDecorView();
    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle);
    mMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogMessage);
    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    super.setTitle(title);
    mTitle.setText(title);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(int titleId) {
    super.setTitle(titleId);
    mTitle.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(titleId));
}

/**
 * Set the message text for this dialog's window.
 * 
 * @param message
 *            - The new message to display in the title.
 */
public void setMessage(CharSequence message) {
    mMessage.setText(message);
    mMessage.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

/**
 * Set the message ID
 * 
 * @param messageId
 */
public void setMessage(int messageId) {
    mMessage.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(messageId));
    mMessage.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

you can use it in any Activity by passing the title and  message

```
mCustomizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(myActivity.this);
 mCustomizeDialog.setTitle("Title");
 mCustomizeDialog.setMessage("Message");
 mCustomizeDialog.okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mCustomizeDialog.dismiss();
                 });
mCustomizeDialog.show();
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom layout for progress

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

 <RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/progress_backgroundimage"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:padding="10dip">

              <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              />

              <TextView  android:id="@+id/text_message"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress_bar"
              android:text="Loading Please wait..."
              android:textSize="10dip"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_margin="10dip"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This progressDialog with backgroud i hope this will be help to you

[Change background of ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog)

Answer (score -1):

[How can I change the background of Android alert dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs)

I think this same way would work on progressdialog aswell.