# Use Holo theme only for dialogs

Tags: android, android-theme

It is possible to use Holo theme only for dialogs?

I declared the app theme with Theme.Black.NoTitleBar in the manifest, and every time I want to instantiate a dialog (ProgressDialog for example) I use

```
new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.default_system_theme);
```

This style is declared in two xml files, based on the android version: one with the holo theme and the other one with the old theme.

The theme is actually applied, but here is the result.

[image]

As you can see, the background is not transparent and the dialog is shown at the top of the screen.

Where am I wrong?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Setting the R.style.default_system_theme property with Theme.Holo.Dialog and Theme.dialog ( depending on android version) here is the result.

[image]

There is still the background even if it doesn't fill up the entire screen. Ho can I get rid of it?

Comment: use `Theme.Holo.Dialog`

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan, but it still doesn't work. I've put the result with your edit in the answer.

Comment: You should take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes thank you! I've just put `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>` inside the definition of the dialog style.