# Set Spinner background colour without removing default dropdown indicator icon

Tags: android, styles, spinner, background-color

Please let me know how I can change background colour for a spinner in Android.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue" />
```

Above code adds the colour BLUE but it also hides the default drop down icon.
Is there a way without using custom background xml to add colour and not hide the icon?

Thanks
Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900017/how-to-customize-the-progress-dialog-in-android ..go through this link for answer

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy workaround. Just wrap your **Spinner** in a **FrameLayout** (for exapmle) and set background color of your choice to the **Layout**.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but its an old question. I don't remember where I used it. Will find out and test your code.

Comment: I know it's an old question but it might help others struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah :). I will check and revert on this

Answer (score 0):

add hexdecimal  number for blue `android:background="HEX_COLOR_CODE"` or use `android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"`

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000FF" />
```

Comment: this is what I am doing right now... but it hides the default icon
same code as above