# Android. Double background AlertDialog

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

everybody!
Forgive, I badly know English...

I have one problem. My AlertDialog have double background. Look:

http://screenshotuploader.com/s/1406rn7lr

The external background - was made by me.
Internal background - I don't know as it to clean.
I have two options:

1. to clean an internal background
2. or to clean an external background, but then to change the internal

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme));
//AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog, null);
builder.setView(view);

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.alert_dialog_full_dark);
return dialog;
```

}

This code builds dialod
This XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text in Dialog"
        style="@style/big_text" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="edit"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Help me, please.
Thanks!

Yes!!! I found the answer!
[Change background of ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog)

Style for API9 (maybe API8... I'm don't know):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_full_dark</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_full_dark</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_top_dark</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_top_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_center_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_center_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@drawable/alert_dialog_center_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_bottom_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_bottom_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/alert_dialog_bottom_dark</item>
</style>
```

Style for API11 and more:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme11</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme11" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme11.AlertDialogStyle11</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme11.AlertDialogStyle11">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_full_dark</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_full_dark</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_top_dark</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_top_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_center_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_center_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@drawable/alert_dialog_center_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@drawable/alert_dialog_bottom_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@drawable/alert_dialog_bottom_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/alert_dialog_bottom_dark</item>
</style>
```

It was necessary to find style of the bottom bar (button) and color of points of the list in dialogue