# How do I change only background color of ProgressDialog without affecting border in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the following code to change the background of Progress Dialog. But the color changes on the outside frame too as below. I want to change only inside the dialog.

```
<style name="StyledDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:background">#083044</item>
</style>
```

[image]

As per the answer given at this question [Change background of ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog)

```
<style name="StyledDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

This code gives background color perfect. But since, dialog color and activity's background color is same. It appears **like transparent with no border. I want some border as before.**

[image]

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347539/change-background-of-progressdialog)

Comment: I am now having a perfect answer. But this question is marked as duplicate, I cannot add answer. Let me add Later.

Answer (score 5):

```
 <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="StyledDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkblue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This code <item name="android:background">@color/darkblue</item> makes background color perfect. But since, dialog color and activity's background color is same. It appears like transparent with no white border. I've derived the another answer from your answer and worked perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
<style name="StyledDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">#083044/item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">#083044</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">#083044</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This code makes background color perfect. But since, dialog color and activity's background color is same. It appears like transparent with no white border. I've derived the another answer from your answer and worked perfect. Thanks.