# How to modify the color of the frame below a floating window?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to change the default transparent grey color around a DialogFragment (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007272/326849)).

I only managed to do it setting `android:windowIsFloating` to false and `android:windowBackground` to the color I want:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

If I set `android:windowIsFloating` to true, `android:windowBackground` has no effect.

How can I do that with `android:windowIsFloating` set to true?