# Translucent activity & DialogFragment = Background around still shown

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a FragmentActivity that makes at the beginning a fragment transacation loading a DialogFragment which builds an AlertDialog. The theme of the Activity is set to @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.
I tried all and I am not being able to show the DialogFragment without the background around.

Please do not care about the red ones, I only obfuscated my app. The green color is the problem is the backgound that I want to get rid of, if I set the color to Transparent, it is still shown in white.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the DialogFragment and call it with show() you will get the background around, not matter if you set the background color to transparent. If you do a fragment transaction to show the DialogFragment, then you can change the color of the background around, and set it to Transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Set android:windowIsFloating to false and android:windowBackground to my custom color in the dialog style.

See similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007272/how-to-change-the-background-color-around-a-dialogfragment)