# How to remove second background under DialogFragment with own style

Tags: android, background, dialog, styles, themes

I want to make two skin application and fast change background in dialogs.
I have DialogFragments and when i want to display my own theme i do it by:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialog);
```

And in styles.xml i have:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
</style>
```

but it's doesn't works.
How to remove that second background selected here:
http://i62.tinypic.com/2i29dzr.png
background between yellow lines

Comment: which one do you mean? The button's background?

Comment: use `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent` think that it will solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

As for me I'm using this style to remove background of dialog, and it works for me perfectly:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It works without 4th item, but how to change background color of buttons and text above button?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15022647/3225458 solution, maybe it will be helpful.