# Using an Alertdialog changes the textviews behind

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I'm using an `AlertDialog` to show the result of a game. My problem is that the dialog seems to changes the depiction of my normal `activiymain` layout while the dialog is open.

That's the layout without the dialog

[image]

That's the layout while the dialog is open

[image]

As you can see the Textviews that i use as buttons are colored weirdly. 
My Dialog is created like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
turnout.setTitle("Dialog");
```

The mainactivity layout is a relative layout and the textviews are colored in #ffffff (meaning white)

Comment: I don't really see any difference, but this little "grey shadow" on the background is something Android use to make the popup more evident, if you don't want it, using a fragment popped up as a dialog might be the solution

Comment: Or check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007272/how-to-change-the-background-color-around-a-dialogfragment) and set the color for the area around the dialog according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Android dims the background (displays the "grey shadow" behind the dialog) whenever a dialog is displayed. Changing this default behavior may decrease the readability of a dialog and confuse a user.

That being said, you can disable the background by setting the parameter `android:backgroundDimEnabled` to `false` in your dialog's style.

You add the theme to your **styles.xml**:

```
<style name="NoDimAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Make sure to inherit the default `AlertDialog`'s style.

Additionally you can control the transparency of the dim, using `android:backgroundDimAmount`. This parameter takes a value from 0 (no dim) to 1 (background completely black). By default Android seems to use 0.6.

```
<style name="LessDimAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.25</item>
</style>
```

Next, pass the style name to the`AlertDialog.Builder`'s constructor in your **MainActivity.java**:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.NoDimAlertDialog)
    .setTitle("Some title")
    .setMessage("Some message")
    .show();
```

You may as well consider using a Fragment to display your AlertDialog. Android comes with handy `DialogFragment` class for that scenario. A simple DialogFragment in your case may look like that:

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.NoDimDialog)
            .setTitle("Some title")
            .setMessage("Some message")
            .create();
    }
}
```

Then you add your Fragment in **MainActivity.java**:

```
new MyDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogTag");
```