# How to do title in center in Dialog for Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

How to make Today Ad title in Center in this dialog in android.

**Code:**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Today Ad");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    dialog.show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025605/custom-dialog-on-android-how-can-i-center-its-title