# set two titles?

Tags: android

I can setTitle("My Title"), but what I'm looking to do is set two titles... one on the left side and one on the right. How might I do that?

I currently have 2 textviews, aligned parent left and right... the textappearance is changed. But I'm hoping to get that into the titlebar using code so I don't have to use some background to simulate the titlebar.

Comment: Have you seen this done before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom view layout and tell the system to use it with:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.text_title);
```

You can make your title view a RelativeLayout with two children positioned as you like. This should be done in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820398/android-change-custom-title-view-at-run-time) for more discussion of using a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can...I think Android only allows one title...but what you could do is

```
setTitle("My Title left                       My title right");
```

It's more than a little bit of a hack but it might work.

Full disclosure: haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this tutorial](http://oo-androidnews.blogspot.com/2010/03/android-how-to-add-custom-title-bar.html) for skinning / theming your titlebar

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing around with some files right now to try and create this dual title bar.
It looks like this post would be helpful: [my_own_titlebar_backbutton_like_on_the_iphone](http://www.anddev.org/my_own_titlebar_backbutton_like_on_the_iphone-t4591.html).
The comment written on this post at Thu Jan 29, 2009 5:55 pm contains the sample files, title1.zip, a second source file, title2.zip is a few comments below that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Bluetooth Chat example on the Android Resources page, [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html), you'll see that it has exactly that sort of format. Details on how to access it are included there. It contains an XML edit and a few other simple modifications in your initialization code.