# How to show android alert dialog in Webview?

Tags: javascript, android

I am Developing an app with webview but I don't know how to enable JavaScript to show alert dialog in webview.

I ever tried this one but it's isn't work for me.
firstly,I made webview and websettings object
then set following parameters.

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634319/how-to-set-different-title-for-alert-dialog-when-webview-page-is-loaded

Comment: @Ganesh: you want to show android native AlertDialog (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As Per Your Code i thought you don't set following setting Webviewclient and Webcromeclient to enable Javascript in Webview.

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Then you load your Html page with following code.

```
 mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+Your_Html_Page);
```

And This is Html part in your Webview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
</html>
```

try this might be helpful.

Comment: Perfect. this solved an issue I was having with getting a JS alert to show, thanks a lot.

Comment: It's working when I add the above two line. But how can I remove the url on top of alert message.

Answer (score 6):

It is not mandatory to use `WebChromeClient` if you want to display message box from JavaScript `alert` function. You can create interfaces between your JavaScript code and **client-side Android code**.

In the below example, your JavaScript code **can call a method in your Android code** to display a `Dialog`, instead of using JavaScript's `alert()` function. I found that this is the most convenient and widely supported way to display alerts.

Include the following classes in your Android application:

**File: WebAppInterface.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a Message box from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void androidAlert(String message) {
        DialogBox dbx = new DialogBox();
        dbx.dialogBox(message, "I get it", "",mContext);
    }
}
```

**File: DialogBox.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class DialogBox {    
    public boolean dialogBox(String msg, String okButton, String cancelButton, final Context activity) {
        Dialog v = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
        if (okButton != "") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(okButton,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { /**/ }
                    });
        }    
        if (cancelButton != "") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(cancelButton,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { /**/ }
                    });
        }

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Next, **bind** the `WebAppInterface` class to the JavaScript that runs in your `WebView` with `addJavascriptInterface()` and name the interface `Android`:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

This creates an interface called `Android` for JavaScript running in the `WebView`. At this point, your web application **has access to the** `WebAppInterface` class. Below is some HTML and JavaScript that creates a  message box using the new interface when the user clicks a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Alert!" onClick="javascript:Android.androidAlert('It works!');" />
```

At the click of the button, the `Android` interface is used to **call the** `WebAppInterface.androidAlert()` method.

**A bit of warning:** Using `addJavascriptInterface()` allows JavaScript to control your Android application. This can be a **very useful feature** or a **dangerous security issue**. As such, you should not use `addJavascriptInterface()` unless you wrote all of the HTML and JavaScript that appears in your `WebView`.

Answer (score 1):

To enable JavaScript dialogue on your webview, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918340/5886712)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public OnClickListener imageButtonViewOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);

// error here
View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.DialogWebView);
myWebView.loadData(webContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
builder.setView(alertDialogView);

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}).show();
}
};
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView android:id="@+id/DialogWebView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to show a native AlertDialog from an event in WebView, then this is what u r looking for [Binding JavaScript code to Android code](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

The sample code is available on this link..The example there show a Toast..u can show an AlertDialog insted.