# Is there a way to detect if a popup is currently being displayed in an Android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have an Android app with a webview that displays a form with a bunch of controls on it. Tapping on one of the controls results in a popup being displayed. Is there a way to detect if a popup is currently active in a webview?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a way to detect just any popup in a `WebView`. There is a way to capture some events in a `WebView` such as when a user taps a link and a link is requested. You should consider something along the lines of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20917793/394933

Answer (score 0):

I've made 2 assumptions because the question came across slightly vague:

- case 1:popup as in dialog showing

  case 2:popup as in an ad showing

**For case 1:**
I can think off two ways to get around this.

Via the android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)  you can call the isShowing() method to determine if a dialog (popup) is showing, it will return true.

**The other way.**

Going by the limited information...have you tried setting implementing a web interface class and calling a function that will indicate whether your dialog is showing? Like this.

```
public class WebAppInterface {

Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** inform user that a dialog is being displayed */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public boolean dialogIsShowing() {
      //  Toast.makeText(mContext, "the dialog is showing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return true
    }
}
```

...

```
//code embeded with html to display your dialog

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showCranialsurgesDialog() {
        Android.dialogIsShowing()
    }
</script>


//handle the result of the dialog showing
if (dialogIsShowing()==true){

//do something
}
```

**For case 2:** popup as in ad is showing

My best guess is to use the: 
      'webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false)' method. This stops windows from opening automatically which from theory not experience may prevent your problem. That documentation is  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(boolean))

Lasty this may be helpful too if case 1 is what your stuck on.  [CLICK ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494135/how-to-show-android-alert-dialog-in-webview)

Hope that helps,
Jonny 2 plates

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response. Essentially the popup I am referring to is a list of options that overlays the rest of the webpage being displayed by the webview when a button is pressed. I need this to show, but would like to know when it is showing in order to process something at this time. I'll poke around these options and see if I can put something together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on the mainActivity the event

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) 
{
    WebView view = getCurrentFocus();
    String url = view.getUrl() ;
}
```

and check if it is the same url two time consecutive

Comment: you need to cast the View to a WebView