# Android: Set Background Drawable of a Custom Titlebar

Tags: android, drawable

Well I guess I ran into some bugs.

There seems to be a bug with Bitmaps in LayerLists: http://www.michaelpardo.com/2011/10/repeating-bitmaps-inside-layerlists/

I have Layer-List that I want to use as a Background-Drawable in my custom titlebar.

```
<style name="custom_titlebar_background">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_titlebar_background</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT:**
To use the linked workaround I need to set the background of the titlebar programmatically, but I have no idea how. This doesn't seem to work, It changes the background of the whole screen (including the actual content view):

```
LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_titlebar_background);
        setLayerDrawableBitmapsRepeating(layer);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(layer);
```

Is there any way to get a reference to a custom titlebar to call setBackgroundDrawable() or any other way to set the background of a custom titlebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It is completely dirty and makes use of undocumented Members. This will work at least for me since my custom title bar is only use on 2.x devices to get a Holo-like Look.

It seems that the android title view has always the same id.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820398/android-change-custom-title-view-at-run-time
        LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_titlebar_background);
        setLayerDrawableBitmapsRepeating(layer);

        // get title view and set new background view
        try
        {
            // retrieve value for com.android.internal.R.id.title_container(=0x1020149)
            int titleContainerId = (Integer) Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id").getField("title_container").get(null);
            View titleView = findViewById(titleContainerId);

            if(titleView != null)
            {
                titleView.setBackgroundDrawable(layer);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // nothing, just skip
        }
```

As long as you are not doing important stuff and your application will still work without it, I see no reason to not use this workaround to fix tileable bitmaps on older Android builds.

Answer (score 1):

Create your Custom title bar like this:

`res/layout/mytitle.xml` - This is the view that will represent the title bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/myTitle"
  android:text="This is my new title"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

`res/values/themes.xml` -

Create a theme that inherits the default theme and set the background style to our own style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>   
    </style> 
</resources>
```

`res/values/styles.xml` - This is where we set the theme to use the background you want for the title background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
   <style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_titlebar_background</item>                   
    </style>
</resources>
```

In the `AndroidMANIFEST.xml`, set the theme attribute either in the application (for the whole application) or in the activity (only this activity) tags

```
<activity android:name=".CustomTitleBar" android:theme="@style/customTheme" ...
```

From the Activity (called CustomTitleBar) :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);

}
```

Comment: I've edited my question. I'm not looking for how to make a custom titlebar. I need to apply a workaround because of an Android bug.